# How to get a Surface from a SurfaceTexture for MediaCodec?

Tags: android

MediaCodec can render directly to a Surface, which can be setted by the [configure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#configure(android.media.MediaFormat,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.media.MediaCrypto,%20int)) method:

```
public void configure (MediaFormat format, 
                Surface surface, 
                MediaCrypto crypto, 
                int flags)
```

I have working code that renders to a `SurfaceTexture`. Also, `Surface`'s [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html) says that

> A Surface is generally created by or from a consumer of image buffers
>   (such as a SurfaceTexture, MediaRecorder, or Allocation),

But I didn't find any methods in `SurfaceTexture` or `Surface` that permits conversion between them

Comment: Hello, there is no conversion per se. Surface is produced from a SurfaceTexture, not the other way around. Check this post for a more complete explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161526/surfacetexture-attachtoglcontext-and-surface